# Donnée une réponse, dans quelle mesure les corrections par son auteur sur le fond sont-elles permises?

Tags: support, editing

Cette question « meta » concerne seulement les corrections sur le fond et pas du tout sur la forme. La possibilité matérielle qu'a un auteur de corriger ses propres réponses n'implique apparemment pas de limites, ni dans le nombre de fois que l'opération puisse être répétée sur une même réponse, ni dans le temps après avoir écrit la réponse, ni dans le volume de texte ajouté ou retranché. En réalité ce n'est pas si simple. Au fil de l'accumulation de savoir pour une question « fr » donnée, celui-ci sous forme de nouvelles réponses, de commentaires et de votes, tout fournisseur de réponse est le plus souvent assuré d'avoir à absorber de nouvelles notions, à la fois à propos du sujet de la question « fr » et à propos de sa propre réponse; en conséquence d'acquérir de nouvelles convictions il est amené éventuellement à rectifier ses vues et les changements dans celles-ci peuvent être comme le jour et la nuit; de ce fait, des modifications sont souvent souhaitables. Il y a plusieurs contextes dans lesquels des corrections pourraient être apportées mais peu qui ne soulèvent pas de doute quant à la légitimité de pouvoir les faire. Je n'en relève que quatre ci-dessous, les plus évidents, et je ne cherche pas à rentrer dans trop de détails.

A - **L'information qui motive une correction est entièrement due à l'auteur de la réponse « fr »**.

1. Pour ce qui est de cette possibilité, il n'y aurait pas de dilemme tant que la réponse n'a pas reçu de vote ni la mention « meilleure réponse ».
2. Les choses sont cependant différentes si cela n'est pas le cas : les jugements qui ont été passés ne correspondent plus à ce qui est écrit après la modification; il résulte de cela des données faussées : essentiellement, il s'agit des votes négatifs; par exemple, le lecteur ne trouve pas un vote qui corresponde lorsqu'il trouve « -2 » alors que la réponse corrigée ne comporte plus d'erreur. Toutefois, cet aspect est peut être considéré comme étant sans conséquence.
   *Peut on faire des modifications dans ce cas?*

B- **L'information est due à l'apport d'un autre auteur mais en réponse à la même question, et aucun jugement n'a été passé sur la réponse dont la correction est envisagée.**

1. La modification ne nécessite aucune mention de l'apport (par exemple, de l'apport il découle qu'une assertion est fausse et il suffirait de l'éliminer).
    
   *Y a-t-il des objections à faire les modifications?*
2. Les changements entrainent le besoin de mentionner des éléments de l'apport. Par exemple, la réponse dont la correction est envisagée comprend l'assertion « Il n'y a pas de possibilité de la situation « A ». » et une autre réponse contredit cela par la seule fourniture d'un cas exceptionnel, sans formuler le principe général; le fait d'une simple modification dans de telles circonstances semble tenir beaucoup du plagiat.
   *Des modifications sont-elles dans une certaine mesure encore possibles?*

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange est un compromis entre un wiki, où chaque page est une œuvre collective et tout le monde peut éditer à condition de respecter le sujet et de chercher à améliorer le traitement ; un blog, où chaque page est l'œuvre de son auteur qui peut la modifier comme il veut ; et des groupes de discussion où l'on édite rarement des messages, même les siens.

[image: diagramme autrefois visible sur stackoverflow.com/about]

Les règles de base pour modifier les messages d'autrui sont disponibles [dans l'aide](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/editing) (en anglais). On trouvera des compléments (en anglais aussi) sur le site méta principal : [d'un point de vue technique](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work), et [concernant l'étiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts).

Pour résumer :

### Éditer son propre message

Chacun est libre d'éditer ses propres messages. En particulier, s'il s'agit de corriger quelque chose de faux, toute amélioration est la bienvenue. Les votes positifs sont beaucoup plus fréquents que les votes négatifs et comptent beaucoup plus pour la réputation, donc un score initial négatif n'a que très peu d'impact à long terme. Il faut juste respecter quelques règles de bon sens :

- Ne pas éditer une question d'une façon qui invaliderait les réponses déjà postées, sauf si c'est indispensable (par exemple parce que la question était ambiguë et que des réponses en font des interprétations différentes).
- Éviter d'éditer trop fréquemment. Chaque édition remet la question au sommet de la page d'accueil. Corriger une faute ou rajouter un complément après coup, pas de problème. Rajouter une phrase toutes les 5 minutes pendant une heure, non. Si vous sentez que la réponse n'est pas mûre, attendez avant de poster.
- Ne pas retirer du contenu sous prétexte qu'on est pas content avec le site : ce serait du vandalisme. On ne reprend pas ses billes si on boude.

Vous pouvez tout à fait intégrer des observations dues à d'autres. Si vous copiez leurs mots, [il est impératif d'indiquer clairement qu'il s'agit d'une citation et qui en est l'auteur](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Si quelqu'un vous a donné une idée mais que l'écrivez avec vos propre mots, il est bienvenu de remercier la personne qui a donné l'idée, soit dans la réponse même, soit dans le message d'édition (« Edit summary »).

### Éditer une question d'autrui

- Encouragé : donner un titre et des étiquettes plus expressives.
- Encouragé : ajouter des précisions que l'auteur a posté en commentaire, s'il ne l'a pas fait lui-même.
- Encouragé : corriger des fautes de français ou d'anglais dans la façon de poser la question (la métalangue).
- À éviter : ne pas corriger des fautes dans les mots ou phrases sur lesquelles porte la question. Même si ce n'est pas l'objet principal de la question, s'il y a par exemple une faute d'orthographe dans une phrase d'exemple, il vaut mieux le signaler comme remarque supplémentaire dans la réponse.

### Éditer une réponse d'autrui

Il est encouragé d'éditer les réponses d'autrui pour apporter des corrections mineures qui ne dénaturent pas la réponse : fautes d'orthographe ou de grammaire, mise en forme, lien cassé, ajout de lien utile (par exemple à un ouvrage de référence), ajout d'un cas oublié... Par contre, si une réponse est complètement fausse, ne la corrigez pas, écrivez la vôtre.